# How to concatenate 2 function in php

Tags: php, function, web

I have the following code:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['function'])){ 
        $_GET['function'](); 
} 

?>
```

So if i entered this url: 
http://localhost/?function=phpinfo

I will see the phpinfo function output on the screen.

can i have a way to concatenate 2 function in the url like this example:

http://localhost/?function=shell_exec('ls') AND phpinfo

So i want to see the first function output..

If you may asking why i need this, is because i am pen testing an web application with this situation..

Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

With your given code example it is not possible to do what you want. All your functions, so `shellexec('ls')` and `phpinfo` will be interpreted as one string, which is then called as a function in by calling it with added parenthis.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think of is using a variable parameter list, rather than just a single parameter. Get all the GET parameters in the function, and loop through them, executing each one.

Comment: Hey, i think you didnt understand me, i have only access to the url and not to the source code, so i can manipulate only with the parameters that i can insert in the url without a way to change the source code..

Comment: Then I suggest that this isn't the right place to ask this question as it doesn't relate to programming. I'd suggest the Information Security exchange perhaps.